# Dificuldade no desenvolvimento de um joguinho

Tags: python, lógica

Estou implementando um jogo, contra o computador, que segue este formato:

> Sejam `N` o número de peças inicial e `M` o número máximo de peças que é
>   possível retirar em uma rodada. Para garantir que o computador ganhe
>   sempre, é preciso considerar os dois cenários possíveis para o início
>   do jogo:
>
> Se `n` é múltiplo de `(m+1)`, o computador deve ser "generoso" e convidar
>   o jogador a iniciar a partida; Caso contrário, o computador toma a
>   inciativa de começar o jogo. Uma vez iniciado o jogo, a estratégia do
>   computador para ganhar consiste em deixar sempre um número de peças
>   que seja múltiplo de `(m+1)` ao jogador. Caso isso não seja possível,
>   deverá tirar o número máximo de peças possíveis.

Como parte do exercício, é obrigatória a implementaçào das seguintes funções:

- `computador_escolhe_jogada` recebe `N` e `M` e devolve um inteiro correspondente à próxima jogada do computador de acordo com a estratégia vencedora.
- `usuario_escolhe_jogada` que recebe os mesmos parâmetros, pede que o jogador informe sua jogada e verifica sua validade, devolvendo o valor informado.
- `partida` que não recebe nenhum parâmetro, solicita ao usuário que informe os valores de `N` e `M` e inicia o jogo, alternando entre jogadas do computador e do usuário. A escolha da jogada inicial deve ser feita em função da estratégia vencedora, como dito anteriormente. A cada jogada, deve ser impresso na tela o estado atual do jogo, ou seja, quantas peças foram removidas na última jogada e quantas restam na mesa. Quando a última peça é removida, essa função imprime na tela a mensagem "O computador ganhou!" ou "Você ganhou!" conforme o caso.

Ao final de 3 partidas, preciso mostrar o resultado do "campeonato", com o número de partidas vencida por cada jogador, mas não consigo fazer a função funcionar.

```
def computador_escolhe_jogada (n,m):
    n = n - m
    print ("O computador tirou ",m," peças")
    print ("Agora restam",n," peças no tabuleiro.")
    return n
    return m
    if n == 0:
        print ("Vitoria do computador")
        C = C + 1



def usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m):
    x = int(input("Digite quantas peças deseja retirar: "))
    while not( x <= m ):
         x = int(input("Digite quantas peças deseja retirar: "))
    n = n - m
    print ("Voce tirou ",m," peças")
    print ("Agora restam",n," peças no tabuleiro.")
    return n
    return m
    if n == 0:
        print ("Vitoria do usuario")
        U = U + 1


U = 0
C = 0

def partida():
    n = int(input("Digite quantas peças: "))
    m = int(input("Digite o limite de peças por jogada " ))

    if n % (m + 1) != 0:
        while (n > 0):
            usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
            if n > 0:
                n = n - m
            computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
    else:
        while( n > 0):
            computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
            if n > 0:
                n = n - m
            usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a questão e indente o código corretamente.  Lembrando que, em Python, código com indentação incorreta é erro de sintaxe. Experimente colar seu código como vem do editor, e usar o botão de "formatar como código" da interface daqui. Tenho a impressão que você colou o código e só "empurrou" as linhas que começavam na coluna 0 pra frente.

Comment: O @jsbueno tem razão... Como o Python não tem marcadores de bloco de código, é basicamente impossível pra gente saber onde cada `if` ou `def` termina... Recomendo também explicar o jogo - e o problema exato que você está tendo - você mesmo, ao invés de colar o enunciado. Muito do que está ali é irrelevante pra resolver o problema exato que você tá encontrando.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara. Qual exatamente é a sua dificuldade? Vc diz que "não consegue fazer a função funcionar". Qual função?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Python - Jogo NIM](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184192/python-jogo-nim)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Na verdade essa outra que é duplicata desta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, sim, mas é que esta foi editada erroneamente e inviabilizou a resposta. Como lá foi respondido, marquei esta como duplicata para relacionar as perguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de tu ter tornado as variáveis C e U globais o Python exige que você  que você identifique como global dentro da função. Isso pode ser feito assim:

```
global C
C = C + 1
```

Assim, a função vai entender que não se trata de uma variável local que não está inicializada. :)