# Python - Jogo NIM

Tags: python

## Enunciado

Você deverá escrever um programa na linguagem Python, versão 3, que permitá a uma "vítima" jogar o NIM contra o computador. O computador, é claro, deverá seguir a estratégia vencedora descrita acima.

Sejam **n** o número de peças inicial e **m** o número máximo de peças que é possível retirar em uma rodada. Para garantir que o computador ganhe sempre, é preciso considerar os dois cenários possíveis para o início do jogo:

Se **n** é múltiplo de **(m+1)**, o computador deve ser "generoso" e convidar o jogador a iniciar a partida. Caso contrário, o computador toma a inciativa de começar o jogo. Uma vez iniciado o jogo, a estratégia do computador para ganhar consiste em deixar sempre um número de peças que seja múltiplo de **(m+1)** ao jogador. Caso isso não seja possível, deverá tirar o número máximo de peças possíveis.

Seu trabalho, então, será implementar o Jogo e fazer com que o computador se utilize da estratégia vencedora.

## Seu Programa

Com o objetivo do EP já definido, uma dúvida que deve surgir nesse momento é como modelar o jogo de forma que possa ser implementado em Python 3 correspondendo rigorosamente às especificações descritas até agora.

Para facilitar seu trabalho e permitir a correção automática do exercício, apresentamos a seguir um modelo, isto é, uma descrição em linhas gerais de um conjunto de funções que resolve o problema proposto neste EP. Embora sejam possíveis outras abordagens, é preciso atender exatamente o que está definido abaixo para que a correção automática do trabalho funcione corretamente.

O programa deve implementar:

- Uma função `computador_escolhe_jogada` que recebe, como parâmetros, os números **n** e **m** descritos acima e devolve um inteiro correspondente à próxima jogada do computador de acordo com a estratégia vencedora.
- Uma função `usuario_escolhe_jogada` que recebe os mesmos parâmetros, solicita que o jogador informe sua jogada e verifica se o valor informado é válido. Se o valor informado for válido, a função deve devolvê-lo; caso contrário, deve solicitar novamente ao usuário que informe uma jogada válida.
- Uma função `partida` que não recebe nenhum parâmetro, solicita ao usuário que informe os valores de **n** e **m** e inicia o jogo, alternando entre jogadas do computador e do usuário (ou seja, chamadas às duas funções anteriores). A escolha da jogada inicial deve ser feita em função da estratégia vencedora, como dito anteriormente. A cada jogada, deve ser impresso na tela o estado atual do jogo, ou seja, quantas peças foram removidas na última jogada e quantas restam na mesa. Quando a última peça é removida, essa função imprime na tela a mensagem "*O computador ganhou!*" ou "*Você ganhou!*" conforme o caso.

Observe que, para isso funcionar, seu programa deve sempre "lembrar" qual é o número de peças atualmente no tabuleiro e qual é o máximo de peças a retirar em cada jogada.

### Campeonatos

Como todos sabemos, uma única rodada de um jogo não é suficiente para definir quem é o melhor jogador. Assim, uma vez que a função `partida` esteja funcionando, você deverá criar uma outra função chamada `campeonato`. Essa nova função deve realizar três partidas seguidas do jogo e, ao final, mostrar o placar dessas três partidas e indicar o vencedor do campeonato. O placar deve ser impresso na forma

---

## Código

```
computador = 0
usuario = 0
rodada = 0

def computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m):
    global computador
    n = n - m
    if (n == 1):
        print(" ")
        print("O computador tirou %s peça." % n)
        print("Agora restam %s peças no tabuleiro." % n)
        print(" ")
        if (n == 0):
            print ("Fim do jogo! O computador ganhou!")
            partida()
    else:
        print(" ")
        print("O computador tirou %s peça." % m)
        print("Agora restam %s peças no tabuleiro." % n)
        print(" ")
        if (n == 0):
            print ("Fim do jogo! O computador ganhou!")
            partida()
    return n
    return m


def usuario_escolhe_jogada(n, m):
    global usuario
    print(" ")
    n_user = int(input("Quantas peças você vai tirar? "))
    print("Voce tirou %s peças." % n_user)
    if (n_user <= m):
        n = n - m
        print(" ")
        print("Agora restam apenas %s peças no tabuleiro." % n)
    else:
        while (n_user > m):
            print("Oops! Jogada inválida! Tente de novo.")
            print(" ")
            n_user = int(input("Quantas peças você vai tirar? "))
    if (n == 0):
        print ("Vitoria do usuario")
    return n_user
    return n
    return m

def partida():
    global computador
    global usuario
    global rodada
    while(rodada <= 3):
        rodada = rodada + 1
        if (rodada <= 3 ):
            print(" ")
            print("**** Rodada %s ****" % rodada)
            print(" ")
            n = int(input("Quantas peças? "))
            m = int(input("Limite de peças por jogada? "))
            if (((n )%(m + 1)) == 0):
                while (n > 0):
                    print(" ")
                    print("Voce começa!")
                    usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
                    if n > 0:
                        n = n - m    
                    computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
                    n = n - m
                    computador = computador + 1
            else:
                print(" ")
                print("Computador Começa!!")
                while( n > 0):
                    computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
                    computador = computador + 1
                    n = n - m
                    if n > 0:
                        usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
                        n = n - m
        else:
            print("**** Final do campeonato! ****")
            print(" ")
            print("Fim de Campeonato: Computador %s x 0 Usuario " % computador)
        break

print("Bem-vindo ao jogo do NIM! Escolha:")
print(" ")
print("1 - para jogar uma partida isolada ")
tipo_jogo = int(input("2 - para jogar um campeonato "))
print(" ")
if ( tipo_jogo == 1 ):
    print("Voce escolheu partida isolada!")
if ( tipo_jogo == 2):
    print("Voce escolheu um campeonato!")
    partida()
else:
    pass
```

Meu problema está quando o usuário inicia a partida, por exemplo: se eu coloco **N=3** e **M=2**, o usuário deve iniciar, quando usuário retira o máximo de peças (duas), o computador também retira duas, ficando um número de peças negativas na mesa e encerra o campeonato.

Comment: Não é a mesma que: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177176?

Comment: É o mesmo, mas fui solicitado a fazer uma nova pergunta. O  jogo dele não segue os parâmetros solicitados e esta faltando informações ao comparar o print, alem da questão não estar resolvida.

Comment: É só isso o enunciado do problema? O que seria "tirar uma peça"?

Comment: O enunciado é enorme, porem no link que voce informou acima, ja contem uma parte. Conforme o código e o print, quando da inicio na partida, o jogo pergunta o "n" numero de peças e "m" máximo de peças.

Comment: Grande, mas essensial para entender o problema. Não sei porquê retiraram da outra.

Comment: vou tentar editar e  adicionar para ajudar.

Comment: Já li na outra, mas ao meu ver é essencial ter. Analisarei seu código aqui.

Comment: adicionei a pergunta.

Comment: Por quê há vários `return` em cada função?

Comment: Resposta do professor : Você não está devolvendo nada nas funções XXX_escolhe_jogada. Você vai precisar mudar seu programa para que partida() chame as funções alternadamente recebendo de cada uma o valor da jogada atual.

Comment: Curiosidade: Que curso é e qual seu nível de conhecimento em programação?

Comment: Coursera, Python pela USP. Sou iniciante amigo.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para um formato aceitável, dentro dos padrões do SOpt.

Comment: Obrigado pela apoio! notei que o calculo da jogada do computador esta errada, coloquei um print(n) no inicio da função do computador_escolhe e percebi que o n acaba ficando negativo, e isso impacta no resultado, independente de quem inicia.

Comment: Estou respondendo aos poucos, vai acompanhando aí.

Comment: Por uma questão de curiosidade, eu comecei a verificar a possibilidade de quem ganhar numa partida de NIM a partir de um vídeo (acho que [esse aqui](https://youtu.be/PN-I6u-AxMg)). Para NIM com uma pilha e tirando até três peças, só há uma possibilidade de quem vencer ser o segundo lugar. Fiz essa demonstração em Java, nesse [projeto aqui](https://github.com/jeffque/ia-games/tree/master/src/main/java/br/com/jeffque/ia)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Selecionando o tipo de jogo

Primeiro, vamos resolver o problema de saber qual tipo de jogo que será executado: `partida` ou `campeonato`.
Sua lógica funciona muito bem nesta parte, então vamos mantê-la.

```
tipo_jogo = 0

# Enquanto não for uma opção válida:
while tipo_jogo == 0:

    # Menu de opções:
    print("Bem-vindo ao jogo do NIM! Escolha:")
    print(" ")
    print("1 - Para jogar uma partida isolada")
    print("2 - Para jogar um campeonato")

    # Solicita a opção ao usuário:
    tipo_jogo = int(input("Sua opção: "))
    print(" ")

    # Decide o tipo de jogo:
    if tipo_jogo == 1:
        print("Voce escolheu partida isolada!")
        partida()
        break
    elif tipo_jogo == 2:
        print("Voce escolheu um campeonato!")
        campeonato()
        break
    else:
        print("Opção inválida!")
        tipo_jogo = 0
```

A estrutura com o `while` é basicamente para repetir enquanto o usuário não digitar uma opção válida. Quando for 1, a função `partida` é chamada. Quando for 2, a função `campeonato` é chamada.

#### Função `partida`

Agora vamos definir a função `partida`. Como solicitado, a função não possui parâmetros e deve solicitar ao usuário os valores de **n** e **m**, iniciando o jogo após isso.

```
def partida():

    print(" ")

    # Solicita ao usuário os valores de n e m:
    n = int(input("Quantas peças? "))
    m = int(input("Limite de peças por jogada? "))

    # Define uma variável para controlar a vez do computador:
    is_computer_turn = True

    # Decide quem iniciará o jogo:
    if n % (m+1) == 0: is_computer_turn = False

    # Execute enquanto houver peças no jogo:
    while n > 0:

        if is_computer_turn:
            jogada = computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m)
            is_computer_turn = False
            print("Computador retirou {} peças.".format(jogada))
        else:
            jogada = usuario_escolhe_jogada(n, m)
            is_computer_turn = True
            print("Você retirou {} peças.".format(jogada))

        # Retira as peças do jogo:
        n = n - jogada

        # Mostra o estado atual do jogo:
        print("Restam apenas {} peças em jogo.\n".format(n))

    # Fim de jogo, verifica quem ganhou:
    if is_computer_turn:
        print("Você ganhou!")
        return 1
    else:
        print("O computador ganhou!")
        return 0
```

A lógica dela é bem simples e auto explicativa pelos comentários do código. É solicitado ao usuário os valores de **n** e **m**. Verifica quem iniciará: se **n** for múltiplo de **m+1**, então o usuário começa, por isso a variável `is_computer_turn` passa a ser falsa. Executa um `while` enquanto houver peças no jogo, isto é, `n > 0`. Verifica, através da variável `is_computer_turn`, de quem é a vez e chama a respectiva função, retornando a quantidade de peças que foram tiradas. Desconta-se do valor total de peças, `n = n - jogada` e volta para o ínicio do *loop*. Quando `n = 0`, encerra-se o *loop*, dando o jogo como finalizado. Se acabou na vez do computador, significa que o usuário tirou a última peça e ganhou, caso contrário, foi o computador que tirou a última peça, ganhando o jogo.

#### Função `usuario_escolhe_jogada`

A função mais simples do jogo. Solicita ao usuário o número de peças que ele quer retirar. Se for um número válido, isto é, maior que 0, menor ou igual a **m**, número máximo de peças por rodada, e menor ou igual a **n**, número atual de peças no jogo. Enquanto o número não for válido, continue solicitando.

```
def usuario_escolhe_jogada(n, m):

    # Vez do usuário:
    print("Sua vez!\n")

    # Define o número de peças do usuário:
    jogada = 0

    # Enquanto o número não for válido
    while jogada == 0:

        # Solicita ao usuário quantas peças irá tirar:
        jogada = int(input("Quantas peças irá tirar? "))

        # Condições: jogada < n, jogada < m, jogada > 0
        if jogada > n or jogada < 1 or jogada > m:

            # Valor inválido, continue solicitando ao usuário:
            jogada = 0

    # Número de peças válido, então retorne-o:
    return jogada
```

#### Função `computador_escolhe_jogada`

A ideia é sempre fazer o computador vencer. Então a primeira condição que temos é: o computador pode retirar todas as peças (`n < m`)? Se sim, retorne o valor de **n**, ou seja, todas as peças restantes do jogo. Caso contrário, o computador sempre buscará manter o número de peças sendo múltiplo de **m+1**, para que o usuário não possa ganhar. Esta condição é feita calculando o resto de divisão de **n** por **m+1**. Será sempre um valor entre 0 e **m**, inclusive. Se for maior que 0, então será o número de peças que o computador precisa tirar para que **n** fique sendo múltiplo de **m+1**. Se for 0, não há como deixar um múltiplo, então retire o máximo que der, **m**.

```
def computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m):

    # Vez do computador:
    print("Vez do computador!")

    # Pode retirar todas as peças?
    if n <= m:

        # Retira todas as peças e ganha o jogo:
        return n

    else:

        # Verifica se é possível deixar uma quantia múltipla de m+1:
        quantia = n % (m+1)

        if quantia > 0:
            return quantia

        # Não é, então tire m peças:
        return m
```

#### Função `campeonato`

A função campeonato irá apenas executar três vezes a função `partida` e contabilizar o placar:

```
def campeonato():

    # Pontuações:
    usuario = 0
    computador = 0

    # Executa 3 vezes:
    for _ in range(3):

        # Executa a partida:
        vencedor = partida()

        # Verifica o resultado, somando a pontuação:
        if vencedor == 1:
            # Usuário venceu:
            usuario = usuario + 1
        else:
            # Computador venceu:
            computador = computador + 1

    # Exibe o placar final:
    print("Placar final: Você  {} x {}  Computador".format(usuario, computador))
```

> Veja o código completo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/GfaZyF), também no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/FjxW/0) ou ainda no [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/6b2993f727db4afd9f0c6bedccc84709).

Comment: Bom dia Anderson, interessante este  "if n % (m+1) == 0: is_computer_turn = False"  desconhecia.

Comment: É um `if` normal, mas como só possui uma instrução, pode ser escrito *inline*.

Comment: Entendi! Na minha logica, independente de quem inciava, o computador acabava escolhendo um valor incorreto e só foi possível visualizar com print(n) no inicio da função. Sua logica corrige a tomada de decisão e o computador passa a escolher o valor correto. Muito obrigado pelo apoio, ensinamento e clareza do código.

Comment: O que geralmente causa estranheza é utilizar o caractere `_` no `for`, na função `campeonato`. É meio que uma convenção no Python quando o valor da iteração não importa muito, como nesse caso. Só precisamos rodar 3 vezes, sem importar muito com qual é a partida que está sendo executada.

Comment: Até estranhei mas tratei como se fosse o famoso for "i" ... .  Ainda é possível aproveitar ele para printar a rodada já incrementando o volor dela a cada roda.

Comment: Sim, ele funciona como uma variável normal, mas já fica explícito que ele não é fundamental para a lógica subsequente. Diferente seria se o usasse como índice de um vetor, aí seria melhor o uso do `i`, ou outro semelhante. Como diz a [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3), **Explicit is better than implicit.**.

Comment: Entendi, acredito e agora sei que devo usar muito ao decorrer do meu aprendizado. Outra coisa nova pra mim, foi o uso do .format(xxx), também desconhecia, pois estudando em livros aprendi a usar o %s. 
Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Então se encante com [isso](https://pyformat.info/).

Comment: caraca... que da hora!!

Answer (score 0):

As strings (textos para o usuário) tem que estar exatemente iguais ao do exemplo do jogo funcionado. E tem mais, a mensagem "Voce começa" ou "Computador começa" deve aparecer apenas uma vez! Caso contrário o corretor automático irá acusar que 'deveria começar pelo...'

```
def partida():
    # Solicita os valores de n e m
    n = int(input("Quantas peças? "))
    m = int(input("Limite de peças por jogada? "))
    # Define um controlador para quem irá começar o jogo
    x = n % (m + 1)
    # Define um controlador para mensagem que avisa quem irá começar
    primeira_vez_usuario = False
    primeira_vez_computador = False

    if x != 0: # Define que o computador irá começar
        pcJoga = True
        primeira_vez_computador = True # Define que é a primeira jogada do computador
    if x == 0: # Define que o usuário irá começar
        pcJoga = False
        primeira_vez_usuario = True # Define que é a primeira jogada do usuário
    # Entuanto tiver peças(n) no jogo...
    while n > 0:
        if pcJoga == True: # Verifica se o computador começa
            if primeira_vez_computador == True: # Verifica se é a primeira vez do computador
                print("")
                print("Computador começa!")
                print("")
            primeira_vez_computador = False # Define que o computador já jogou a primeira vez
            # Variavel recebendo retorno do número de peças que o computador tirou
            vlr_tirado = computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
            # Define que é a vez do usuário
            pcJoga = False
            # Definindo se a mensagem é ficará no singular ou no plural
            if vlr_tirado == 1:
                print("O computador tirou uma peça")
            else:
                print("O computador tirou ",vlr_tirado," peças.")
        else: # Se não for o computador quem começa, então é o usuario...
            # Verifica se é a primeira vez do usuário
            if primeira_vez_usuario == True:
                print("")
                print("Voce começa!")
                print("")
            primeira_vez_usuario = False # Define que o usuário já jogou a primeira vez
            # Variavel recebendo retorno do número de peças que o usuário tirou
            vlr_tirado = usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
            # Define que é a vez do computador
            pcJoga = True
            # Definindo se a mensagem é ficará no singular ou no plural
            if vlr_tirado == 1:
                print("Você tirou uma peça")
            else:
                print("Voce tirou",vlr_tirado,"peças.")
        n = n - vlr_tirado # Remove do tabuleiro as respectivas peças tirada de cada rodada.
        # Para não mostrar que restam 0 peças
        if n > 0:
            print("Agora restam",n,"peças no tabuleiro.")
            print("")
    # Verifica quem jogou por último, e mostra a mensagem respectiva
    if pcJoga == True:
        print("Fim do jogo! Você ganhou!")
        print("")
        return 1 # ID para contabilizar quantas partidas o usuário ganhou no campeonato
    else:
        print("Fim do jogo! O computador ganhou!")
        print("")
        return 0 # ID para contabilizar quantas partidas o computador ganhou no campeonato


# Função que retorna quantas peças o usuário irá tirar do tabuleiro
def usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m):
    vlr_tirado = 0
    # Enquanto o usuário não digitar um valor válido, ficará preço aqui
    while vlr_tirado == 0:
        vlr_tirado = int(input("Quantas peças você vai tirar?"))
        # Verifica se o valor digitado pelo usuário é valido
        if vlr_tirado > n or vlr_tirado > m or vlr_tirado < 1 :
            print("")
            print("Oops! Jogada inválida! Tente de novo.")
            print("")
            vlr_tirado = 0 # Se for inválido mostra a msg e retorna para o loop
    return vlr_tirado # Se não, retorna o valor tirado


# Função que retorna quantas peças o computador irá tirar do tabuleiro
def computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m):
    if n <= m: # Se o numero de peças for menor que o máximo
        return n # Apenas retorna o mesmo numero de peças para tirar e ganhar logo
    else:
        sobrou = n % (m+1) # sobrou recebe o resto da divisão
        if sobrou > 0:  # Já que não é menor que m, e maior que 0 então...
            return sobrou # retorne o resto
        return m # Se não, retorne o máximo de peças possíveis


# Função que chama partida 3 vezes
def campeonato():
    # Define um controle de placar
    computador = 0
    usuario = 0
    # Define um controle de partidas
    i = 1
    for _ in range(3):
        print("**** Rodada",i,"****")
        print("")
        id_ganhou = partida()
        i = i + 1 # Conta as partidas
        if id_ganhou == 1:
            usuario = usuario +1 # Conta pontos para usuário no placar
        else:
            computador = computador + 1 # Conta pontos para o computador no placar
    print("**** Final do campeonato! ****")
    # Mostra os respectivos placares...
    print("Placar: Você",usuario,"X",computador,"Computador")

# O programa começa aqui, o usuário irá definir a modalidade
escolha = 0
while escolha == 0:
    print("")
    print("Bem-vindo ao jogo do NIM! Escolha:")
    print("")
    print("1 - para jogar uma partida isolada")
    print("2 - para jogar um campeonato 2")
    escolha = int(input())
    if escolha == 1:
        partida() #Inicia uma partida
        break
    elif escolha == 2:
        print("Voce escolheu um campeonato!")
        print("")
        campeonato() # Inicia um campenato
        break
    else:
        print("Escolha uma opção válida!")
        print("")
        escolha = 0 # Volta para o loop, enquanto não escolher 1 ou 2
```

Comment: olhando rapidamente tem uma falha de loop infinito em usuario_escolhe_jogada, o input tem que estar dentro do while

Answer (score 0):

Corrigido de acordo com as Strings pedidas e funcionando 100%:

```
def campeonato():
usuario = 0
computador = 0
x = 1
for _ in range(3):
    print("\n**** Rodada {} ****\n".format(x))
    x = x + 1
    vencedor = partida()
    if vencedor == 1:
        usuario = usuario + 1
    else:
        computador = computador + 1
print("\n**** Final do campeonato! ****\n")
print("Placar: Você {} x {} Computador".format(usuario, computador))

def computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m):
if n <= m:
    return n
else:
    quantia = n % (m+1)
    if quantia > 0:
        return quantia
return m

def usuario_escolhe_jogada(n, m):
jogada = 0
while jogada == 0:
    jogada = int(input("Quantas peças você vai tirar? "))
    if jogada > n or jogada < 1 or jogada > m:
        print("\nOops! Jogada inválida! Tente de novo.\n")
        jogada = 0
return jogada

def partida():
n = int(input("Quantas peças? "))
m = int(input("Limite de peças por jogada? "))

is_computer_turn = True

if n % (m+1) == 0: 
    is_computer_turn = False
    print("\nVocê começa!\n")
else:
    print("\nComputador começa!\n")

while n > 0:

    if is_computer_turn:
        jogada = computador_escolhe_jogada(n, m)
        is_computer_turn = False
        if(jogada == 1):
            print("\nO computador tirou uma peça.")
        else:
            print("\nO computador tirou {} peças.".format(jogada))
    else:
        jogada = usuario_escolhe_jogada(n, m)
        is_computer_turn = True
        if(jogada == 1):
            print("\nVocê tirou uma peça.")
        else:
            print("\nVocê tirou {} peças.".format(jogada))


    n = n - jogada

    if(n == 1):
        print("Agora resta apenas uma peça no tabuleiro.\n")
    elif(n > 1):
        print("Agora restam {} peças no tabuleiro.\n".format(n))

if is_computer_turn:
    print("Fim do jogo! Você ganhou!")
    return 1
else:
    print("Fim do jogo! O computador ganhou!")
    return 0

    tipo_jogo = 0
while tipo_jogo == 0:
    tipo_jogo = (int(input("Bem-vindo ao jogo do NIM! Escolha: \n\n1 - para jogar uma partida isolada \n2 - para jogar um campeonato ")))
    if ( tipo_jogo == 1 ):
        print("\nVoce escolheu partida isolada!")
        partida()
        break
    elif ( tipo_jogo == 2):
        print("\nVoce escolheu um campeonato!")
        campeonato()
        break
    else:
        print("Opção inválida!")
        tipo_jogo = 0
```

Answer (score -2):

****Função def partida****

Prezados eu fiz uma pequena alteração na def partida() porque quando executei, independente do resultado da divisão, o jogo era sempre iniciado pelo computador. Abaixo minha alteração:

```
is_computer_turn = True
    if x != 0:
        is_computer_turn = True
        print("O computador começa!") 
    if x == 0:
        is_computer_turn = False
        print("Você começa!")
```

Comment: Quais foram seus valores de entrada? Lembre-se que a lógica do jogo fará com que o computador inicie na maioria das vezes. Se `n` for múltiplo de `m+1`, por exemplo, `n=6` e `m=2`, será o usuário que começará o jogo. Na minha solução isso aparenta estar funcionando perfeitamente. Tem como melhorar sua resposta e descrever melhor qual foi o problema que você solucionou?

Comment: Olá Andreson, qqer valor que eu informava o computador iniciava o jogo, eu achei bem estranho e fui fazendo testes até chegar na solução que compartilhei ( que pode não necessariamente ser a melhor, mais funcionou). Obrigado por seu comentário.