# Como acessar variáveis definidas em outra função?

Tags: python

Estou escrevendo um programa sobre o jogo do NIM. Ele pede pra que eu chame funções dentro de outra função, mas quando eu tento computar variáveis pertencentes a esta função em outra função (a função que chama a que contém a variável) aparece uma mensagem de erro dizendo que não identifica o nome da variável. Eu tentei de todos os jeitos consertar isso, mas não consegui:

```
def computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m):
    m2 = 1
    while (m2 <= m) and (((n-m2)%(m+1)) != 0):
        m2 = m2 + 1
        return m2


def usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m):  
    m1 = int(input('Quantas peças você vai tirar? '))
    while m1 > m:
        print()
        print('Oops! Jogada inválida! Tente de novo.')
        print()
    return m1
    print('O jogador removeu',m1,' peças')

def partida():

    n = int(input('n? '))
    m = int(input('m? '))
    while n > 0:
        if (n%(m+1) == 0):
            print('Você começa!!!')
            usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
            print('Agora restam', n - m1,'peças no tabuleiro')

        if (n%(m+1)!=0):
            print('O computador começa')
            computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
            print('Agora restam', n - m2,'peças no tabuleiro')
        n = n - m1 - m2
```

Ele diz que o `m1` não está definido, mas ele está definido sim, só que na função de cima. Como faço para a outra função reconhecê-lo?

Olá pessoal obrigado a todos pelas contribuições. Acontece que se eu armazenar m1 = usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m) m2 = computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m)

O programa simplesmente executa as funções mais uma vez e nao retorna as variáveis. E o exercício exige que não se use variáveis globais (é um requisito do exercício :)

Comment: No contexto atual, não há `m1`. Por que não passar `m1` e `m2` como parâmetros?

Comment: Aproveitando, tem como formatar corretamente seu código? Basta selecionar ele e apertar ctrl+k

Comment: Que jogo é esse ? Quais são as regras desse jogo ?

Comment: Talvez vale a leitura de: [Python - Jogo NIM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184192/5878)

Comment: Olá a todos, sou novo no STACK OVERFLOW, essa é minha primeira pergunta, desculpem-me pelos erros. Obrigado pela ajuda de todos. As regras do jogo são as que seguem

Answer (score 3):

Quando você define uma variável **dentro** de uma função, essa variável existe apenas durante o tempo de execução da função. Para que você possa usar os valores de m1 ou m2, os mesmos deveriam ser variáveis globais, ou serem armazenados de alguma forma. Vamos por partes:

```
def computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m):
    m2 = 1
    while (m2 <= m) and (((n-m2)%(m+1)) != 0):
        m2 = m2 + 1
        return m2
```

Sua primeira função recebe dois parâmetros o `n` e o `m` e os usa para fazer os respectivos cálculos inerentes ao jogo e armazenar na variável `m2`. Mote que você declara a variável **dentro** da função, assim, como eu disse la em cima, ela só existe durante a execução da função.

**Como resolver? :**

Note que suas funções **retornam** valores, ou seja elas **se tornam** os valores, assim é possível armazenar esses valores em variáveis. Dessa forma:

```
def computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m):
    m2 = 1
    while (m2 <= m) and (((n-m2)%(m+1)) != 0):
        m2 = m2 + 1
        return m2

m2 = computador_escolhe_jogada(10,20) # Valores hipotéticos
```

Dessa forma a variável declarada **fora** do escopo da função assume o valor da sua função, no caso o valor de `m2`.

**Ok, mas como isso fica na prática ?**

```
.
.
.
n = int(input('n? '))
m = int(input('m? '))
while n > 0:
    if (n%(m+1) == 0):
        print('Você começa!!!')
        m1 = usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
        print('Agora restam', n - m1,'peças no tabuleiro')

    if (n%(m+1)!=0):
        print('O computador começa')
        m2 = computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
        print('Agora restam', n - m2,'peças no tabuleiro')
    n = n - m1 - m2
```

Seu erro provavelmente estava nessa linha : `print('Agora restam', n - m1,'peças no tabuleiro')` Note que o programa não conseguiria chamar `m1` porque ela era uma variável que existia **apenas** dentro das suas funções

Quando você armazena o resultado dessas funções em variáveis globais:

```
m1 = usuario_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
m2 = computador_escolhe_jogada(n,m)
```

O programa passa a reconhece-las e poder lidar com seus valores.

Espero tenha te ajudado de alguma forma.

Answer (score 1):

Você também poderia optar pelo uso do "global" dentro da função. Isso te permitiria visualizar a variável dentro daquele escopo. Exemplo:

```
def exemplo():
    global X 
    X = 'Valor da Variável'
    return X
```

Neste caso, se você imprimir o valor da variável X, ainda que fora da função (Se você já houver executado a função, é claro). Ela terá o valor "Valor da Variável" que foi definida dentro da função.

Comment: É uma alternativa. Eu creio que não seja o ótimo para o AP, mas é uma alternativa válida. Eu deixaria o código um pouco mais próximo da dúvida